# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating image filters using Angular but I am getting below error.

```
image = document.querySelector('img');
filterControl = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]');

applyfilter(){
let computedFilters ='';
this.filterControl.forEach(function(item,index) {
  computedFilters += item.getAttribute('data-filter') + '(' + item.value + item.getAttribute('data-scale') + ')';
});
this.image.style.filter = computedFilters;
}
```

Error:

```
item.value (Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339))
```

This is my HTML

```
    <input id="sepia" type="range" onchange="applyFilter()" [(ngModel)]="sepia"  data-filter="sepia" data-scale="%" step="0.1" min="0" max="1"> Sepia
                <span id="Amount_sepia">({{sepia}})</span><br/>
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `value` property does not exists on `element` type. you should convert it to `inputElement` type in order to access the `input` property `let input = item as InputElement`

Comment: As usual :"Hello, I have a problem in Angular". The code : `querySelectorAll`, `getElementById`. Classic. Again, _this. is. not. how. Angular. works._ I have no idea why everybody keeps trying to select elements in the DOM using Javascript selectors or jQuery in an Angular app. No tutorial EVER uses them. But Everybody tries, fails, and comes to Stackoverflow asking why. `querySelectorAll`, `getElementById` etc. have no business at all in Angular because Angular just doesn't work this way. Please, _follow the tutorials_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Element` type is general for **all** html element (not only inputs) and yes - there are no `value` property in that type. In order to enjoy using  TypeScript, we need to understand that sometimes casting an object to a specific type **IS A MUST**. in our use-case the type is `HTMLInputElement` which represens inputs (which got `value` property). So:

```
this.filterControl.forEach(function(item: HtmlInputElement, index: number) {
  if (!item) return; // maybe there are other elements which are not inputs like div, span, etc.
  computedFilters += item.getAttribute('data-filter') + '(' + item.value + 
  item.getAttribute('data-scale') + ')';
});
```

Comment: thank you so much getting error in HTMLInputElement  we have to define right in the top

Comment: can you please let me know why iam getting error in inputElement